# Twig form builder rendering time

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, silex

I'm using Twig to build form like this :

**Class :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 5)))
        ))
        ->add('mail', 'email', array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Email())
        ));
}
```

**Twig :**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-less-padding">
    {{ form_start(contactForm, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal pull-left'} }) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(contactForm.name, null, { 'label_attr':  {
                'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
            }}) }}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ form_widget(contactForm.name, { 'attr':  {
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(contactForm.mail, null, { 'label_attr':  {
                'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
            }}) }}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ form_widget(contactForm.mail, { 'attr':  {
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
            </div>
        </div>
    {{ form_end(contactForm) }}
</div>
```

But it looks like it really impacts on the rendering time of my pages. For exemple, static pages have a total rendering time of 350-400ms but when I click on this contact page, the total rendering time is 800-850ms.

I'm in dev environment (so I'm not using Twig cache option or gzip compression) and the debug toolbar says that controller took 652ms and Twig templates 387ms. **Is that a correct time?**

**Debug stats screenshot : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpm66.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSL6R.png)**

I have only one controller file HomeController.php for the whole site (it's a small site so there is only 9 functions in it) - **is that a problem?** ; here is the function concerning the contact action :

**HomeController :**

```
/* 8 others functions */

public function contactAction(Request $request, Application $app) {
    $book_id = $app['dao.home']->returnBookId();
    $contactForm = $app['form.factory']->create(new ContactType());
    $contactForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($contactForm->isSubmitted() && $contactForm->isValid()) {
        $formData = $contactForm->getData();
        $msg = 'New message from'.$formData['name'].'('.$formData['mail'].') <br><br>';
        $msg .= 'Content : '.$formData['content'].'';
        mail("mail@gmail.com","New message",$msg);
        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your message was sent successfully.');
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('contact.html.twig', array(
        'active_page' => 'contact',
        'book_id' => $book_id,
        'contactForm' => $contactForm->createView()));
}
```

So **is using the form builder a good way to build form?** Or **maybe should I build the form myself with two html inputs and a submit button?**

Also, **when is it advisable to use the form builder rather than create the inputs myself in the view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 450ms is not THAT much, you should not worry, don't forget:
   "premature optimization is root of all evil".
2. is that in dev environment ? if yes, then probably in production (with symfony cache) it will be less
3. in dev environment in debug tolbar you can see which part took most
   time - what that says ?
4. i'm not sure what do you mean by "hand build" the form, but you
   should use forms like in symfony book - if you use some "direct" methods of assembling form object instead of formbuilder, i doubt that there would be difference in speed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question to properly give you all the details.

Comment: 652ms seems a lot for "contact form" controller, can you post here whole controller code ?

Comment: also make sure you dont run website on very slow server... but if static pages take 450ms, then something is wrong, either whole your PHP stack on your server is slow (very weak server, or server with huge load - is it shared server ?), or you have something that executes every request - perhaps some external bundle or some request listener ?

Comment: In fact, I'm working in local on WAMP so I can't imagine what it will be online... I edited my question with the controller code. By the way, I'm using only one Controller file for the actions of the whole site (only 9 functions) ; maybe that is the problem? - I also added two screenshot of the Debug tool, maybe you will find the problem there.

Comment: i wouldn't worry about it, first run it on production server and see if app is subjectively fast or not. having one controller file is "not a problem", there also is no "correct time" :)

Comment: Indeed, there is a big difference on production. Static pages (only text): 200ms (70ms for the controller); Form pages: 400ms (310ms for the controller). Without neither gzip compression, PHP Accelerator nor twig cache. Is it more "normal"?

Comment: yeah, that is "normal" :)